# Is there any function for customizing the List View event times

Tags: fullcalendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u23rt.png)

I do not want to manipulate the DOM directly by event render Hooks

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat

Comment: slotLabelFormat is used for the time grid, not the list view. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry it should be https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat

Comment: I used eventTimeFormat, but with some special time it does not show up friendly, i want customize it
ex: 
    events: {..., start:2021-01-01 00:00:00, end: 2021-01-02 00:00:00}
On the user interface, it will show up as 00:00
Expect like I attached the image above

Comment: That isn't possible sorry. And no-one uses 24:00 for midnight anyway, that's not a recognised standard anywhere as far as I know - it will just be confusing / irritating for users

Comment: P.s. if you want it to show "all-day" then just set the all-day flag in the event, or don't include times in the start and end properties